# How to open Spring ModelAndView response in Ajax success method as a complete page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am unable to open `ModelAndView` response given by Spring controller method using Ajax success method.

**Spring Controller method:**

```
    @RequestMapping (value="setupDbEdit.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)

    ModelAndView setupABC(@RequestParam String db_id){
        System.out.println("**hello world**"+db_id);
        ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView("editDB");
        request.setAttribute("dbID", db_id);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping (value="editDB.jsp", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
    ModelAndView addCustomerSetupABC(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView= new ModelAndView("editDB");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

**Ajax code:**

```
$("#editDb").click(function(e){
             $.ajax({
                type: 'GET', 
                'url': 'http://localhost:8080/Test_ReportingUI/setupDbEdit.htm',
                data: {db_id: dbID},
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(response){ 
                    alert(response);
                },
                timeout: 10000,
                error: function(xhr, status, err){ 
                }
            }); 
         });
```

**`editDB.jsp` (The page that I want to open):**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>

alert("hellow");
</script>
<%
String strDBID=(String) request.getAttribute("dbID");
out.println(strDBID+"<br><br>");
%>
This is edit screen for DB details...
</body>
</html>
```

I don't want to open this page in pop up, rather I want to get it open on same page replacing the old.

Comment: Of cause, you can replace `html` node with another one, but anyway your javascript (`alert("hellow");`) will not execute. Because browser dind't load new page by usual manner. It would be better if you'll load and replace just part of page.

Answer (score 3):

On the same page you should specify the target where the returned html text should be injected. For example

```
<div id="result"/>
```

then on `success` handler load the content

```
success: function(response){ 
    $("#result").html(response);
},
```

Comment: how can I open this in pop up window.

Comment: you may use window.open() or better jquery.ui $.dialog

Comment: how can I open response returned on completely new page.

Comment: 1. you have asked to open ti on the *same* page, 2. you can't.